# How to adjust button size according to screen size in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm new to android development, and I am making a calculator in android studio. My calculator works fine but there isa  problem with its layout I installed it on my tablet and the buttons were very small as I designed them in Android Studio on an emulator, the button size doesn't change, and need help so that the button size increases as the screen size changes.

My calculator design in Android Studio

[image: Calculator design]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff000000">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/clear_btn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/plus_minus"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-11dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pm_btn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/per"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/plus_minus"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/plus_minus"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/plus_minus"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-11dp"
        android:background="@drawable/per_btn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/div"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/per"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/per"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/per"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-11dp"
        android:background="@drawable/div_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/disp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/plus_minus"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_below="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/plus_minus"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/plus_minus"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/seven_btn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/eight"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/plus_minus"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/plus_minus"
        android:background="@drawable/eight_btn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/nine"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/per"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/per"
        android:background="@drawable/nine_btn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/mul"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/nine"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/div"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/div"
        android:background="@drawable/mul_btn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="103dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:background="@drawable/four_btn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/five"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/four"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/eight"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/eight"
        android:background="@drawable/five_btn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/six"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/five"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nine"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/nine"
        android:background="@drawable/six_btn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/sub"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nine"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/six"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mul"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mul"
        android:background="@drawable/min_btn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_below="@+id/four"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/four"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/four"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:background="@drawable/one_btn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="203dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/zero"
        android:layout_below="@+id/one"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/one"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/one"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/zero_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-7dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_above="@+id/zero"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/five"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/five"
        android:background="@drawable/two_btn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_below="@+id/five"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/six"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/six"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/three_btn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/three"
        android:layout_below="@+id/six"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sub"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sub"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/plus_btn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/dot"
        android:layout_below="@+id/two"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/three"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/three"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dot_btn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/equ"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dot"
        android:layout_below="@+id/three"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/add"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/add"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/equ_btn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it did not change cause you set the width and height with fixed value. Try using weights

Comment: If you specify a width of 100dp the result should on any device appear to be around 0.6 inch / 1.6 cm wide. If I have a tablet, why would I want giant buttons? One does not simply scale the layout up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use `layout_weight` in order to achieve what you want, and that will be used by wrapping each row of buttons inside a `LinearLayout` and all that `LinearLayouts` plus the `TextView` will be wrapped inside one big `LinearLayout` instead of your `RelativeLayout` like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="6" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/disp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/clear_btn" />

        <!-- then the three remaining buttons -->

        <LinearLayout />

        <!-- then the four remaining rows -->


        <!-- in the last row the "0" button will have layout_weight="2" NOT "1" -->
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**

use ImageButtons instead of Buttons for better scalability, and this is how you must use it:

```
    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/clear_btn"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <!-- and so for all Buttons -->
```

Note here we changed:

1- `layout_height` : from `wrap_content` to `match_parent` .

2- `background` : removing the **drawable**(clear_btn) and making it `transparent`.

and we added:

1- `src` : assigning to it the **drawable**(clear_btn).

2- `scaleType` : making it `fitCenter` to make it scales in all the available area without ruining the Image scalability ratio.

**P.S**: in case you are want the Button to take all the area weather it is scalable or not, change `scaleType` from `fitCenter` to `fitXY` (may be you will need that for the "**0**" Button).

Comment: @Muhammad Refaat    i did as you guided me ( http://s27.postimg.org/t3g0v1ukz/del_mr.png ) but now problem as there is a lot of gap between button vertically and horizontally  , so how can i remove the gap :(

Comment: @user889030 the problem is you are using `Buttons` not `ImageButtons` which will give you much better ability to adjust your views, So, I advice you to replace the Buttons with `ImageButtons` and I will post an update contains the required changes to Buttons.

Comment: Yo have to change Button  android:layout_weight="4" to  android:layout_weight="1" like you write ->   <!-- in the last row the "0" button will have layout_weight="2" NOT "1" -->

Comment: @Ingo yeah that's right, probably mistyping, I corrected it, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to support multiple screens never drag and drop and resize views manually.

You can check both the `android:layout_weight` attribute and `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1:
 please use dimens.xml for specifying with and height for buttons.

for tablet,please create folder values-sw600dp,values-sw720dp and put your dimens.xml inside.

Solution 2:

```
Use linearlayout and layout_weight property.
```

Answer (score 1):

While setting the height/width of a button in android, using fixed density pixel values will result in exact sizes on all screens. Using width values as `wrap_content`, `fill_parent`, weights etc. will make the button look according to the screen densities.

Try going through this link once:-  [Best Practices for User Interface](http://developer.android.com/training/best-ui.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView  
android:id="@+id/sampleRecyclerView"  
android:scrollbars="vertical"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Button android:id="@+id/sampleButton"
 android:width="0dp"
 android:height="50dp">
</Button>
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

I think the point here is `<Button> </Button>` inside a Linear Layout.

```
android:width="0dp" // This line changes width as of linear layout.
android:height="50dp">
```